# Netty client creating several threads per request

Tags: java, multithreading, http, netty

I have a Java Netty client that seems to create around 30-35 threads per request. The client is currently running inside a docker container as a service. When I took a thread dump, I see these `I/O Dispatchers" being those new threads.

```
"I/O dispatcher 31" Id=99 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    -  locked sun.nio.ch.Util$3@237d4416
    -  locked java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet@5bbb333d
    -  locked sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2ef026f8
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
```

I have an ExecutorService fixed thread pool in my application logic, I disabled it and still these threads grow. How can I go about further investigating these? Following is my http client config:

```
java.HttpClientConfig = {

    connectTimeout = 1000;

    maxConnectRetries = 1; 

    maxTotalHttpConnections = 100;

    maxHttpConnectionsPerHost = 100;

    closeAfterUse = true;

    connectionStaleCheckingEnabled = false;
   
    maxReplyThreads = 10;
  };
```

Would appreciate any leads/suggestion/advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally Netty will pool all threads since threads are a pretty expensive resource. I'm not a Netty expert, but normally you create a ServerBootstrap once and keep using it and it will take care of all thread pooling. So I would have a look at that first; how often is a ServerBootstrap created? I would also try to confirm that new threads are actually being created per request because this seems like very weird behavior.

Comment: Please show the code that creates the `Bootstrap` etc.

Comment: Pretty sure you will see about the same number of threads running even when there Are no requests.